# Is it wrong to show a component on a fragment using Angular?

Tags: angular, routes, deployment, authorization, angular-components

I am architecting a website and for some complexity reasons I came up with a solution of showing a data editing component which must be auth-guarded, using *route fragment*.

I was wondering if there could be anything wrong in terms of security issues or any capable drawbacks?

my route would be like:

`http://192.168.1.8:4200/posts/646108d590c2f63c071e7a2a#edit`

when I click the edit button and the `app-post-edit` component will be shown (taking part of the screen) and as shown above the fragment will be attached to the route!

I am using this method to take advatage of ***@Input*** and ***@Output*** decorators for data transferring between the post and the editing post component!

and I would deactivate it using `*ngIf('signedIn')` directive preventing unauthorized access!

```
.
.
.
</div>
<app-post-edit
  [selectedPost]="selectedPost"
  (editClicked)="getEditStatus($event)"
  *ngIf="signedIn"
></app-post-edit>
```

Thanks

Comment: The first part could be achieved by adding the link, the queryparams and the fragment as an input argument to child's selector, for the second part -concerning signIn page- you could move the logic to a guard.